# How to write binary stream as an opus file - python

Tags: python-3.x, opus

I'm trying to write an opus file out of a binary stream using the code below, but the resulting files are unplayable. It seems that dumping it into the container won't work. Any ideas as to how to go about writing these audio files?

> ```
>         audio_start.append(start_audio + name[2])
>         audio_end.append(start_audio + name[2] + name[3])
>     count = 0
>     for i, j in zip(audio_start, audio_end):
>         in_file.seek(0)
>         count += 1
>         audio_output_path = input[:-4] + "audio_" + str(count) + ".opus"
>         with open(audio_output_path, 'wb') as out_audio:
>             out_audio.write(in_file.read()[i:j])
>             out_audio.close()
> ```